# $d\mid (ua + vb)$ and $d\mid(\alpha a + \beta b),$ with $u,v, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\ |u\beta- v\alpha| = 1.$ Prove $d | a$ and $d|b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}: (d$ divides $ua + vb)$ and $(d$ divides $\alpha a + \beta b),$ with 
$$u,v, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}\; \text{ and }\; |u\beta- v\alpha| = 1$$

Prove that $d \mid a$ and $d\mid b$.

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: Voting down is welcome, but if make more sense if you can give a feedback in order to improve the question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing people downvoted because you didn't write what you tried

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$ua+vb= kd$$
$$\alpha a + \beta b = l d$$

Write them in matrix form

$$\begin{bmatrix} u & v \\ \alpha & \beta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} kd \\ ld \end{bmatrix}$$

Solve for $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: multiply $ ua+vb $ by $\beta $ and $\alpha a+\beta b $ by $ v $. Then deduce that $ d\mid a (u\beta -\alpha v) $. Apply the same idea (i.e. multiply by  some convenient number) to deduce that $ d\mid b (u\beta -\alpha v) $.